# TexStudio and TexCount User Command

Tags: perl, count, latex

Im trying to incorporate TexCount into Tex Studio.

Ive gotten the perl script working in the command line, but I would like it done in TexStudio automatically.

I have adapted a bat file, but it doesnt work:

```
@echo off
C:\texlive\2015\texmf-dist\scripts\texcount\texcount.pl -html -inc "?ame" > "%".html
"%".html
```

However I tinker with the syntax it doesnt seem to work and at the very most I can get it to produce a blank html file "_count.html"

Can anybody get this .bat file working please?

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Can you run that exact thing on the command line? Does it work if you run the batch file from command line? Do you think the problem is with the perl code, with the batch code or with TexStudio running the batch file?

Comment: I think the problem is TexStudio running the batch file. The % gives you the name of the file without the extension and ?ame gives you the full path, name and extension. I think the syntax is wrong which is why TexCount isnt getting the right file(s).

Comment: Change the batch file to just output stuff. Maybe to a fixed file of the window closes immediately, or put a break. Then you can see what it fills in.

Comment: I dont really know how to do that, could you give an example please?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it working using the TexStudio User Commands.

In the Menus,

> Options > Configure TeXStudio

Then,

> Build > User Commands

I created my own user command with the name "texcount".

```
texcount %.tex -inc -total
```

This runs the texcount script;

- on the current file (that's what the % is for),
- it includes the files that use \input{},
- it provides a total.

I can now run this command from:

> Tools > User > (Number of user command: name of user command) e.g. 1:
>   texcount

Then the results are output in the messages tab.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: To more specifically produce a html file. I imagine you could use the html commands to produce your html file as shown in Thomas' answer.

You could then pipe the output to something like wkhtmltopdf to produce a pdf from the html file and show it using the default TeXstudio pdf viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I could get this to work on my mac, you may need some adjustments for other OSs and/or other directory structures.

1. I created a script that calls texcount, as follows:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   perl /CorrectPath/texcount.pl -v0 -sum -html "$1*" >tempdoc.html
   open tempdoc.html
   ```
2. In TexStudio, my user command looks like this:

   ```
   "/CorrectPath/count_pdf_words.sh" ?ame"
   ```